# Fiware, wirecloud, enablers and how to integrate them

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm working on my first fiware project. I want to make an application consisting on an online store, with some Specific Enablers to provide some functionality. This is all very new to me, and I've been reading a lot these days, but I'm pretty lost and I really wonder if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Can I use wirecloud to make a mashup application like this? How can I integrate specific enablers with the web application? Is there some kind of enabler to provide online store functionality?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WireCloud comes with support for some of the Generic Enablers provided by FIWARE ([WStore](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/store-wstore), [Orion](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker), [Kurento](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/stream-oriented-kurento), ...) and can be used for accessing to your Specific Enablers (although you will need to code). You can learn more about WireCloud on the available [course](http://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=53) at FIWARE Lab Academy.

One of the Generic Enablers that seems useful for your use case seems to be the [Store Generic Enabler](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/store-wstore). The store is used in FIWARE Lab for distributing/selling services, datasets, and WireCloud components, but can be configured for other purposes.

Comment: Be aware that WStore is not very good to build normal (consumer oriented) stores. From the description; "The design of the Store generic enabler does not focus on consumer-centric mobile apps, but on selling enterprise-level apps and cloud services that..... "

Comment: @Meier so you think that I shouldn't use Wstore if i want to build a marketplace application where I want my users to buy and sell products? I.E the Wstore shouldn't be my foundation?
Alvaro? any thoughts?

Comment: We don't know what you exactly want, or what skills you have. When I evaluated the WStore for a project, it was not a good fit: The advanced features that make the WStore special were not needed for us. On the other side, I think the usability is not like customers expect it from normal store. And is is easier to get help if you use one of the big open source online stores.